# What does the verb "versioning" mean in the context of deriving classes?

Tags: c#, oop

Unfortunately, my native language is not English.

I understand that this is an etymology, but what does it actually means?

I met this terminology here at [MSDN: Versioning with the Override and New Keywords (C# Programming Guide)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6fawty39.aspx).

Comment: It might be more helpful for you to think of "-ing" verbs like nouns. They usually describe an idea or an activity, rather than someone actually performing an action. In this case, versioning is "what happens when old and new code work together". It's not actually an action--you don't "version" the software. (Although you really could say that, nobody does, except when you're saying talking about starting to use version control.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have the a member with the same name in both the base class and the deriving class. Support for 'versioning' as it is called makes sure that evolving classes won't mess up each other.

You have to explicitly tell how you want to version your members. They can be overriding each other (`virtual` and `override`), or live side-by-side (`new`).

Answer (score 1):

In this context 'versioning' refers to the evolution of software, a 'version' meaning a shapshot of the development or release state of the software at a given point in time.

The link refers to technical machinery of the C# language that allows for coherent evolution of software branches (in particular, derived classes need not be tied to the base class of a particular version of the library the base class is contained in. This option might promote software reuse, even across products, teams, organizations [that's the theory. I cannot substantially comment on whether this is true / realistic ]).

You may also be interested in 2 other Stack Exchange sites:

- [English Learners](https://ell.stackexchange.com/)
- [English Language & Usage](https://english.stackexchange.com/)